# How to have different tag than master branch in local git branch

Tags: git, git-tag

I want to have different tags for my `master` and `release` branches. I was wondering how to do this?

I have a git `master` branch with the tag `2.2.2-crown`. When I created a `release` branch, it seems the `release` branch inherited the tag from my `master` branch.

```
$(master): git tag
2.2.2-crown
```

I created one branch,

```
$git checkout -b release_branch
$git tag v3.1
$git tag
2.2.2-crown  <--------------I don't want this tag in my release branch
v3.1
```

I just want to have only release tags not master tag.

Comment: All tags are global; that's the *point* of tags.  And, as in Phillippe's answer, tags aren't "in" branches, they just identify one specific commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git tags are not per branches. Tags are just refs, like branches are, that point to one of the commits of the git history.

You'd better name your tags 'release/v3.1'.

And the git tag command will always list them all.

Comment: Well, thanks for the info. I have suffixed my branch with release names.